# Prime Powers and Differences of Consecutive Cubes

Tags: prime-numbers, elliptic-curves, perfect-powers

I am wondering if it has been proven that there does not exist a prime $p$ and an integer $r \ge 3$ such that $p^r = (n + 1)^3 - n^3$ for some integer $n$.

Note that this is a special case of [Beal's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tijdeman%E2%80%93Zagier_conjecture), where in this case $A = p$, $B = n$, and $C = n + 1$ (and thus $A$, $B$, and $C$ do not have a prime factor).

(To those who are wondering, this is relevant to the classification of elliptic curves $y^2 = x^3 + B$ over $\mathbb{F}_{p^r}$ whose orders are $p^r$.)

Thank you!

Comment: Well, certainly $r$ can't be $3$ or a multiplier of $3$. According to the Fermat's Last Theorem, which was proved, that would be a contradiction. The only options left are $r=3q+1$ and $r=3q+2$