# Diophantine Equation: $4x^r = 3y^2 + 1$

Tags: diophantine-equations

If $r \ge 3$ is an integer, show that $4x^r = 3y^2 + 1$ does not have positive integer solutions $(x, y)$ except for $(1, 1)$. (I am not sure whether this is an open problem; in any case, it is a slightly stronger but probably more familiar form of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1836004/prime-powers-and-differences-of-consecutive-cubes).)

Comment: perhaps working in $$Z(\frac{1+\sqrt{-3}}{2})$$ would work

Comment: Thanks, but could you clarify what technique(s) I might want to use, or give a link to a resource that would explain how working over $Z \left( \frac{1 + \sqrt{-3}}{2} \right)$ would help?

Comment: any book on algebraic number theory should work, provided you know some abstract algebra.

Comment: a nice, introductory read is T.Nagell "Introduction to the theory of numbers", or Hardy and Wright's book http://matematica.cubaeduca.cu/medias/pdf/842.pdf

Comment: start at page 178 of hardy and wright's book, which explains it